# where can i find linux-tools-3.15.0-031500-generic for 14.04?

Tags: 14.04, kernel

I just installed 3.15 kernel and i can't locate the corresponding linux-tools-3.15.0-031500-generic package.
Where can I find it ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can download the `.deb` package of it from [launchpad](https://launchpad.net/~canonical-kernel-team/+archive/ppa/+build/5980376).

Also:

```
wget "https://launchpad.net/~canonical-kernel-team/+archive/ppa/+build/5980376/+files/linux-tools-3.15.0-0-generic_3.15.0-0.1_armhf.deb"
```